# GitHub importing broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, jobs, github

I'm trying to add my GitHub profile to my existing Careers profile. Chrome warns of an endless redirect loop in the target page.

Comment: Apparently it's fixed now :?

Comment: Please feel free to let us know if you're seeing this problem again. At this time, there doesn't seem to be any problem with the GitHub import. Maybe this was a temporary outage.

Comment: I'm still having the same redirection loop with chromium while trying to import my github profile to my career account. Weird thing though - I tried several time and one time I've been redirected to my github profile but nothing had changed on my career account.